# Eq on abstract data type giving error (haskell)

Tags: haskell

trying to remove an element from an abstract data type I made called Map in Haskell, I am using equality to see what key matches up in order to remove the element from the Map

```hs
data Map k v = Map {pairs::[(k, v)]}  deriving (Show)

removeElement :: Eq k -> Map k v -> Map k v
removeElement key (Map pairs) = Map [x |x <- pairs,not(fst x == key)]
```

gives me the error :

```
main.hs:33:18: error:
    * Expected a type, but `Eq k' has kind `Constraint'
    * In the type signature:
        removeElement :: Eq k -> Map k v -> Map k v
   |
33 | removeElement :: Eq k -> Map k v -> Map k v
   |                  ^^^^
<interactive>:3:1: error:
    * Variable not in scope: main
    * Perhaps you meant `min' (imported from Prelude)
```

from my understanding once establishing the Eq k, I don't have to anywhere else and I can't really comprehend what the compiler is trying to tell me, would appreciate help.

Answer (score 6):

In Haskell, `Eq` is not a type but is a typeclass. For typeclasses, you should use `=>` rather than `->`.

You also need to add in a `k` to stand for the argument you are calling `key`:

```
removeElement :: Eq k => k -> Map k v -> Map k v
removeElement key (Map pairs) = Map [x |x <- pairs,not(fst x == key)]
```

Note that there is no argument that corresponds to `Eq k`.

The compiler message, "Expected a type, but 'Eq k' has kind 'Constraint'", is basically saying that `Eq k` is not a type, but you're trying to use it like a type.